# Java command not found on Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash, oracle-enterprise-linux

In Oracle Enterprise Linux when I type `java` I am getting

```
bash: java: command not found
```

I have installed Java 1.6 and I have the following

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
 + 2           /usr/java/jre1.6.0_24/bin/java
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: when you ran update-alternatives --config java, did you select 2? what happened after you select 2 , then ran java command? do you still get the error, java: command not found ?

Comment: @Jasonw I did select 2 by typing 2 and after that I am still getting `java: command not found`

Comment: if you do ls -l /etc/alternatives/java, it should symlink to /usr/java/jre1.6.0_24/bin/java . Then you need to check which  java is called, `which java` and the path given (e.g. /usr/bin/java) , it should symlink to /etc/alternatives/java

Comment: @Jasonw I have resolved the issue by the below mentioned solution by devsundar. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes, that configuration is per user basis. The one with alternative is applicable to system wide. But if you are happy with the solution, that's great! :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can add one of the Java path to PATH variable using the following command.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_24/bin/
```

You can add this line to .bashrc file in your home directory. Adding this to .bashrc will ensure everytime you open bash it will be PATH variable is updated.

Comment: You can also put it in `/etc/profile.d/path.sh` on ubuntu15x

Answer (score 3):

I found the best way for me was to download unzip then symlink your new `usr/java/jre-version/bin/java` to your main bin as java.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following script to update the default alternative after install jdk.

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_BIN_DIR=/usr/java/default/bin # replace with your installed directory
cd ${JAVA_BIN_DIR}
a=(java javac javadoc javah javap javaws)
for exe in ${a[@]}; do
    sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/${exe}" "${exe}" "${JAVA_BIN_DIR}/${exe}" 1
    sudo update-alternatives --set ${exe} ${JAVA_BIN_DIR}/${exe}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I had these choices:

```
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
 + 2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
   3           /home/ec2-user/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java
```

When I chose 3, it didn't work. When I chose 2, it did work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, this site isn't a forum, it's a question and answer site and your other answer is a question. Please don't do this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute: vi ~/.bashrc OR vi ~/.bash_profile

(if above command will not allow to update the .bashrc file then you can open this file in notepad by writing command at terminal i.e. "leafpad ~/.bashrc")

2. add line : export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.6.0_24
3. save the file (by using `shift + Z + Z`)
4. source ~/.bashrc OR source ~/.bash_profile
5. Execute : echo $JAVA_HOME
   (Output should print the path)

Comment: Question was Command "java -version" not working Not echo $JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on my ec2 machine. Below these 2 commands helped me to fix the issue.

sudo yum update

sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto

Answer (score 0):

just run this command

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```