# Not a valid identifier error in UNIX

Tags: java, unix

while using unix I got  **java : command not found** error. So I referred to this stack overflow post   [Java command not found on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237872/java-command-not-found-on-linux). But when i gave the path of Java as suggested in the answer of the above post (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\jre ), i got  **export: `FilesJavajdk1.6.0_41jre': not a valid identifier**. Could anyone please  help me out here.

Comment: Directories and paths on Linux work differently than on Windows. `C:\Program Files\...` is a Windows path, that is not going to work on Linux.

Comment: That answer was for windows obviously. You need to locate java in your system. try `find / -name java`

Comment: You will have to remove the dots in ` jdk1.6.0_41jre . Better change the it to `jre6`

Comment: Where do you see `c:\Program Files` anywhere in the post you've linked to? Fundamentally it sounds like Java probably isn't installed on your machine...

Comment: The StackOverflow post you linked to has no mention of anything in 'C:Program Files'. Are you sure you are on Unix, and if so, what happens if you follow the actual advice in that post (update alternatives)?

Comment: Removed the dots. Guess what!! it's working. Thank you all for your time, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

### you can set the path in this way

JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41"
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

the problem is coming because of the space between Program and Files

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note, that your answer is mixing up Unix and Windows. A syntax like `$JAVA_HOME` and the `export` command exist in Unix shells only, whereas a directory structure like `C:\Program Files\...` is Windows specific.