# Getting out of memory issue while Marshaling large number of objects in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am getting **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** Exception while trying Marshal large number of objects in to XML, however previously i was using less object or less size of xml file that time JAXB **marshaller.marshal(message, fi);**   was absolutely fine. Now as per new requirement in my project we need to increase data that in XML file i have tweak the logic as per new story.
However after tweaking logic i run the report its looks fine 2-3 times after that started throw OOM exception.

Note : i have increase Xms, Xmx  and XX:MaxPermSize but still facing same issue.

Could you guys please help me to get resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you check if the values of Xms, Xmx and XX:MaxPermSize are getting reflected. You can do that by invoking the jmap app in jdk bin folder as below: ./jmap -heap <java process id>

Comment: Hi Praveen, I tried same on linux but "Jmap  coammand not found", i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237872/java-command-not-found-on-linux.

Comment: cd locationOfJdkBin after that do ./jmap -heap processid

Comment: Yes i can see Xms, Xmx and XX:MaxPermSize getting reflected, but i get it from  "ps -ef|grep" command . We dont have access to java installation dir. Any ways parameter as below -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Comment: Can you find the Xmx value and increase it to a larger value to accommodate the increase in data handling of you app. That sould solve the problem

Comment: are you using SAX parser ??

Comment: @praveen I am using JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space is commonly caused when the JVM runs out of heap space.

This can be mainly due to two reasons

```
1. Memory leak
2. excessive computation by the app
```

In your case i assume its the second one causing the problem. This can be solved by setting the Xmx value to a larger value than the current one.

If you are using tomcat you can do this in the setenv.sh inside tomcat bin.
setting `CATALINA_OPTS=Xmx1024M (or any other value)`

Comment: Hi Praveen, I am already using Xmx2048M, however still we are facing same issue. Any ways in case of marshaling we are getting 25 lakh lines in XML, i thought it may be reason of OOM. Can you suggest any thing else that can solve OOM in Jaxb Marshaling.

Comment: @hari what is the max Xmx value that your application can have ? if there is a limitation then can you think of parsing the xml file in batches or some sort of caching strategy.

Comment: this link should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310595/how-to-parse-big-50-gb-xml-files-in-java

Comment: currently we have configured Xmx = 2048M. as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310595/how-to-parse-big-50-gb-xml-files-in-java   we are using JAXB and whole project implemented in same manner. Its tough to revert JAXB in SAX